# Woocommerce custom product inputs / consolidate bloated php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build a very simple plugin for personal use which adds 4 custom text fields to Woo products. My starting point was [this](https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/70b7e07705628b91f0f81926b03c3954) excellent post by [@helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking) which I've adapted using jQuery to place the fields outside of the cart form:

```
/**
 * Display input on single product page
 */
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_fields_inputs', 22 );
function custom_fields_inputs() {

    echo '<div>';

    woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_one', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'personalisation-field') ,
        'label' => __('First line - Front') ,
        'placeholder' => __('max. 15 characters') ,
        'maxlength' => 15,
        'required' => true,
    ) , '');

    woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_two', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'personalisation-field') ,
        'label' => __('Second line - Front') ,
        'placeholder' => __('max. 15 characters') ,
        'maxlength' => 15,
        'required' => false,
    ) , '');

    woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_three', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'personalisation-field') ,
        'label' => __('First line - Back') ,
        'placeholder' => __('max. 15 characters') ,
        'maxlength' => 15,
        'required' => false,
    ) , '');

    woocommerce_form_field('custom_field_four', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array( 'personalisation-field') ,
        'label' => __('Second line - Back') ,
        'placeholder' => __('max. 15 characters') ,
        'maxlength' => 15,
        'required' => false,
    ) , '');

    echo '</div>';

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('#custom_field_one').on( 'input blur', function() {
            $('#hidden_field_one').val($(this).val());
        });
        $('#custom_field_two').on( 'input blur', function() {
            $('#hidden_field_two').val($(this).val());
        });
        $('#custom_field_three').on( 'input blur', function() {
            $('#hidden_field_three').val($(this).val());
        });
        $('#custom_field_four').on( 'input blur', function() {
            $('#hidden_field_four').val($(this).val());
        });
     });
    </script>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Hidden Input
 */
function custom_fields_hidden(){
    $valueone = isset( $_POST['_personalisation_one'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_one'] ) : '';
    $valuetwo = isset( $_POST['_personalisation_two'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_two'] ) : '';
    $valuethree = isset( $_POST['_personalisation_three'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_three'] ) : '';
    $valuefour = isset( $_POST['_personalisation_four'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_four'] ) : '';
    printf( '<input id="hidden_field_one" type="hidden" name="_personalisation_one" value="%s" />', esc_attr( $valueone ) );
    printf( '<input id="hidden_field_two" type="hidden" name="_personalisation_two" value="%s" />', esc_attr( $valuetwo ) );
    printf( '<input id="hidden_field_three" type="hidden" name="_personalisation_three" value="%s" />', esc_attr( $valuethree ) );
    printf( '<input id="hidden_field_four" type="hidden" name="_personalisation_four" value="%s" />', esc_attr( $valuefour ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_fields_hidden', 28 );

/**
 * Validate when adding to cart
 */
function custom_fields_validation( $passed, $product_id, $qty ){

    if( isset( $_POST['_personalisation_one'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_one'] ) == '' ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s cannot be added to the cart until you enter some custom text.', 'kia-plugin-textdomain' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
        return false;
    }

    return $passed;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'custom_fields_validation', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Add custom data to the cart item
 */
function custom_fields_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['_personalisation_one'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['personalisation_one'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_one'] );
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['_personalisation_two'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['personalisation_two'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_two'] );
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['_personalisation_three'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['personalisation_three'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_three'] );
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['_personalisation_four'] ) ) {
        $cart_item['personalisation_four'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_personalisation_four'] );
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'custom_fields_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Load cart data from session
 */
function custom_fields_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values['personalisation_one'] ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_one'] = $values['personalisation_one'];
    }
    if ( isset( $values['personalisation_two'] ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_two'] = $values['personalisation_two'];
    }
    if ( isset( $values['personalisation_three'] ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_three'] = $values['personalisation_three'];
    }
    if ( isset( $values['personalisation_four'] ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_four'] = $values['personalisation_four'];
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'custom_fields_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2 );

/**
 * Add meta to order item
 */
function custom_fields_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

    if ( ! empty( $values['personalisation_one'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'personalisation_one', $values['personalisation_one'] );           
    }
    if ( ! empty( $values['personalisation_two'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'personalisation_two', $values['personalisation_two'] );           
    }
    if ( ! empty( $values['personalisation_three'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'personalisation_three', $values['personalisation_three'] );           
    }
    if ( ! empty( $values['personalisation_four'] ) ) {
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'personalisation_four', $values['personalisation_four'] );           
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'custom_fields_add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Get item data to display in cart
 */
function custom_fields_get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['personalisation_one'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'key' => __( 'First line - Front' ),
            'display' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['personalisation_one'] )
        );

    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['personalisation_two'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'key' => __( 'Second line - Front' ),
            'display' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['personalisation_two'] )
        );

    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['personalisation_three'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'key' => __( 'First line - Back' ),
            'display' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['personalisation_three'] )
        );

    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['personalisation_one'] ) ){

        $other_data[] = array(
            'key' => __( 'Second line - Back' ),
            'display' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['personalisation_four'] )
        );

    }

    return $other_data;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'custom_fields_get_item_data', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Restore custom field to product meta when product retrieved for order item.
 * Meta fields will be automatically displayed if not prefixed with _
 */
function custom_fields_order_item_product( $product, $order_item ){

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_one' ) ){
        $product->add_meta_data( 'personalisation_one', $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_one' ), true );
    }

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_two' ) ){
        $product->add_meta_data( 'personalisation_two', $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_two' ), true );
    }

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_three' ) ){
        $product->add_meta_data( 'personalisation_three', $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_three' ), true );
    }

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_four' ) ){
        $product->add_meta_data( 'personalisation_four', $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_four' ), true );
    }

    return $product;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', 'custom_fields_order_item_product', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Customize the display of the meta key in order tables.
 */
function custom_fields_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $order_item ){

    if( $meta->key == 'personalisation_one' ){
        $display_key =  __( 'First line - Front' );
    }

    if( $meta->key == 'personalisation_two' ){
        $display_key =  __( 'Second line - Front' );
    }

    if( $meta->key == 'personalisation_three' ){
        $display_key =  __( 'First line - Back' );
    }

    if( $meta->key == 'personalisation_four' ){
        $display_key =  __( 'Second line - Back' );
    }

    return $display_key;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'custom_fields_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Order Again
 */
function custom_fields_order_again_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $order_item, $order ){

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_one' ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_one'] = $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_one' );
    }

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_two' ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_two'] = $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_two' );
    }

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_three' ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_three'] = $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_three' );
    }

    if( $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_four' ) ){
        $cart_item['personalisation_four'] = $order_item->get_meta( 'personalisation_four' );
    }

    return $cart_item;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_again_cart_item_data', 'custom_fields_order_again_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
```

As you can see from my code I've managed to insert 4 fields using a lot of duplication - and it actually works for the most part (the only issue is empty fields are still being displayed in cart meta), but even as I made the changes I knew it wasn't good practice - there must be a better way!

I'm by no means a whizz at PHP and have very much been teaching myself as I go but I've hit my limit here. How do I consolidate all this bloated code into something clean and efficient? (hopefully fixing the empty cart meta strings being displayed in the process!)

Comment: Regarding `custom_fields_inputs`: You take the values that are _different_ in each of those calls, and place them into an array - so that you can then _loop over_ the contents of that array, and inside the loop have _one_ call of `woocommerce_form_field`, mixing the dynamic with the static parameters accordingly …

Comment: The following JS part could be simplified using several different ways. If the relation of the fields in the DOM doesn’t allow to determine what hidden field belongs to what input field, then you could add some additional info to the fields, like put the ID of the hidden field, into a custom data attribute on the input field - so that you only need one event handler for all of them, and can read the id of the corresponding hidden field from the input element itself.

Comment: You could also name the fields differently to begin with - instead of `name="something_one"`, `name="something_two"`, use `name="something[0]"`, `name="something[1]"` etc. Then `$_POST['something']` will become an array, that you again can simply loop over, instead of having to write the same code with different `_one`, `_two` etc. suffixes multiple times.

Comment: Great thank you, I've managed to streamline the JS but any changes I've tried to make to simplify everything after are breaking the plugin so I'm definitely doing things wrong. Are you able to get me started with what you'd change to the custom_fields_hidden function and hopefully I can figure the rest out from there?